# Make a static text appear on activity load

Tags: android

I have a piece of code like this :

```
public class myAcitvity extends Activity {
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.activity_mine);
       // Want a text to appear on activity screen after this activity creation , but not a toast.
     }
}
```

Now once the activity has been created , i want a static text to appear like we do in `jsp` using `<c: out>` or `out.print()` . How do i do that in android ?

Comment: Want a text to appear - where in log i.e console or on your activity screen??

Comment: On my activity screen.

Comment: make a `textview` in the `activity_mine.xml` and write you text there.
`android:text="your text"`

Comment: Activity are screens http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html.Each activity depicts the screen view. You want a text visible in your activity layout ie. textview -text in textview remains visible unlike toast that disapears

Comment: read any hello world example for android.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

midify your activity_mine to :

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="TextView" />
```

```
public class myAcitvity extends Activity {
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   setContentView(R.layout.activity_mine);
   TextView t = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
   t.setText("some static text");
 }
```

}

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick. Gonna accept when stack allows me .

Answer (score 0):

You can use Log. 
but I think your need is something else.

Comment: Log is for logging not for making texts come up .

Answer (score 0):

To output to the console use:

```
Log.i("My Error", "Oops, that didn't go so well...");
```

If you want something to appear in the activity you can add something like a TextView in the activity_mine.xml layout file you have:

```
 <TextView android:text="My Text"
    android:id="@+id/title"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
</TextView>
```

or programtically create a view in the onCreate() method:

```
TextView textView = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
textView.setText("My text");
layout.addView(TextView, layoutParams); <- get your parent layout and create params
```